# Application Update of a Kendo-UI mobile application

Tags: mobile, kendo-ui

As we know, an Kendo-UI Mobile application has some major parts:

- HTML files
- JavaScript files
- CSS files
- resource files (images)

My main question is: Is there is a way to update HTML, CSS, JS and other resources? I mean doing this without native OS update procedure.

Could I access KendoUI Mobile storage, where these resources (index.html, etc.) are stored?

Answer (score 0):

If the user accesses your application as a web page, then these files are updated automatically.  Then the goal is to cache them on the local device so that every time the user accesses them, they are not re-downloaded. 
If you want your html + javascript to act like a downloadable app, then Telerik recommends using [Phonegap (aka Cordova)](http://docs.phonegap.com/en/1.8.1/guide_getting-started_ios_index.md.html#Getting%20Started%20with%20iOS) to wrap your html into a downloadable app.  One of the big advantages of Cordova is that it gives your javascript access to the device's features (such as GPS, camera, contacts, and local storage).  Telerik has a dev environment that (Icenium) which makes this extra simple.  Once the user has downloaded your app, the standard mobile practice for updating the app to a new version takes place (ex: the user sees version upgrade badge and chooses which apps will be updated).  For details as to why an app can't simply update all it's files invisibly, [kxb as a great post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13093995/updating-javascript-code-in-cordova-app-after-it-has-been-published-in-the-app-s).