# Cordova on the fly update

Tags: cordova, auto-update, on-the-fly

Yes I know it is possible to do. But i can't see any solid example since it is very useful for Cordova Apps. There isn't any plugin so far. If something goes wrong with newer update from the site of `www/` folder. I would like to update automatically. Is this against to rules of Apple or Google? Are there any solid examples to doing that? I think it should be made on native side to not effect the working logic and restart the application after install?

Notes:I saw already [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13093995/updating-javascript-code-in-cordova-app-after-it-has-been-published-in-the-app-s) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12865316/phonegap-updating-javascript-and-css-without-submitting-the-app-to-appstore) also [this](http://forum.ionicframework.com/t/updating-ionic-apps-on-the-fly/1577)

Comment: I'm not sure to understand your question... Do you want to update dynamically the pages in the www folder of your app ?

Comment: yes pretty much it is. I already know its possible but in enterprise level applicable or Apple do not allow auto updates

Answer (score 0):

As an alternative to what you are looking for, I hardcoded a version no. inside the index.html and on the Server side, I have a global variable 'lowest version supported'.  each time the index.html connects the server, the hardcoded version is compared with the 'lowest version supported', if it is no longer supported, I freeze all functions in that client and display a message to ask the client update to newest version in the market.